# Relationship between flow and resource consumption in VNFs (Middleboxes)

Tags: computer-networks, network-flow, resource-allocation

A middlebox consumes some resources (CPU ticks, RAM, etc.) to process a traffic, e.g., a IDS consume 50% CPU and 20% RAM to process a 100M bps flow.

Here is the problem. 100M bps flow may consume more resource if the flow is processed by a lot computationally expensive rules.

Therefore, my question is that are there any publications (paper, book, etc.) that study about the problem I just mentioned.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're getting at. If you want more processing power, get more hardware.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am trying to schedule in NFV, not to buy a IDS, therefore,  the relationship between resource consumption and flow is kind of crucial.